# How to get id value of Main.mxml file to CustomPanel.mxml file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a method in `CustomPanel.mxml` and I need to use `id` which is available in `Main.mxml`

Below is my sample code

**Main.mxml**

```
<local:CustomDivideBox id="div1">
```

**Custompanel.mxml**

```
private function xxxx(){
  div1.state = (div1.state == CustomDividedBox.COLLAPSE ? CustomDividedBox.EXPAND : CustomDividedBox.COLLAPSE);

}
```

Please provide some sample code.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Is Custompanel.mxml also created in the main.mxml?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the id when you're already in the object?  Use the 'this' operator within your custom component.

```
private function xxxx(){
  this.state = (this.state == CustomDividedBox.COLLAPSE ? CustomDividedBox.EXPAND : CustomDividedBox.COLLAPSE);
}
```

This is very basic OOP concepts and I suggest you read up on that.

EDIT:
Oh wait, those are 2 different components.  What you want to do is dispatch an event within Custompanel.mxml, which Main.mxml listens for and knows what to do in the other component:

Main.mxml

```
customPanel.addEventListener('someEvent', someEventHandler);

private function someEventHandler(e:Event):void
{
   div1.doSomething();
}
```

CustomPanel.mxml

```
private function xxxx(){
   this.dispatchEvent(new Event('someEvent'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reference to the main application you can use:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication
```

In your case though you should listen to J_A_X.